# Making a binary & function using only ~ and |

Tags: c

So my task is to create a function that essentially performs the & operation, but only using ~ and |. So for example if my function is called binaryAnd, binaryAnd(6,5) should return 4. This is my function now:

```
int binaryAnd(int x, int y){
   int result=~x|~y;
   return result;
}
```

the logic is that taking the complement of the 2 numbers then doing | on them should return the same result as just doing &. But when I put 6 and 5 into this function it returns -7 instead of 4. Why is this? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
NOT A OR NOT B = NOT (A AND B)
```

This gives

```
NOT (NOT A OR NOT B) = NOT (NOT (A AND B)) = A AND B
```

You can change the return statement to this :

```
return ~result;
```